# International SSA/STM 3-Layer Model

Tags: debris, tracking, sensors, collision-avoidance

I'm working on a paper outlining an International SSA/STM<sup>1</sup> approach for Civil SSA/STM and have read and referenced many publications.  I believe it was an IDA documents such as https://www.ida.org/-/media/feature/publications/g/gl/global-trends-in-space-situational-awareness-ssa-and-space-traffic-management-stm/d-9074.ashx that suggest a 'as a service' layered model that consists of:

- Value Added Services - such as CA & VCM
- Basic Services - such as ELSETS
- Sensor Networks - raw feeds to/from usually basic services.

however, I can't seem to find that reference anymore!  Has anybody seen this SSA/STM 3-layer model?  Surely, I didn't make this up!?

---

<sup>1</sup> SSA/STM = Space Situational Awareness/Space Traffic Management

- [“Space Situational Awareness: Key Issues in an Evolving Landscape](https://science.house.gov/imo/media/doc/Oltrogge%20Testimony.pdf)
- NOAA Office of Space Commerce [Category: SSA/STM](https://www.space.commerce.gov/category/ssa-stm/)

Comment: I added some help for acronym-challenged readers like me, feel free to edit further.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the document you're looking for might be *Evaluating Options for Civil Space Situational Awareness* (https://www.ida.org/idamedia/Corporate/Files/Publications/STPIPubs/2016/P-8038.ashx), written two years earlier by a slightly different group of IDA folks.  CA is collision avoidance (or conjunction assessment, which amounts to the same thing), and VCM is a name for what they call "element sets that are stored in state vector format with associated covariance".